# Binary Trees in c

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

[image]

Guys I am new to data structures.Most of the time in books and references i see this structure for a binary tree

```
struct btree {
    int data;
    struct btree *left;
    struct btree *right;
};
```

But in above image it would be like

```
struct btree
{
    int data;
    struct btree *left;
    struct btree *right;
    struct btree *parent;
};
```

So my question is that is it dependent on programmer to choose the structure of a node of a tree (for e.g also including a pointer to the parent )or we can have only two pointers one to the left child and other to the right child.

Comment: If you'll never need to traverse upwards, there's no point including the parent node.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is up to you whether you include parent pointers.  They require more work to maintain, but some tree operations (like removing a node given just that node rather than its parent) become much easier.

Comment: could you also tell me how to construct a complete binary tree.What i can't interpret is how we would move in BFS manner for nodes insertion as there is no link between nodes.

Comment: @yogi15490: How do you want to move around the tree?  You use the child pointers for that, and sometimes the parent pointers if you have included them.

Comment: @yogi15490: When inserting, you only need to move *down* the tree, so only child pointers are required.

Comment: Guys still not getting how to insert new node in complete binary tree

Comment: Guys i think i have to use a queue data structure while traversing the tree while doing the insertion in complete binary tree.Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you.  They're generally not required for most tree operations, but they can speed up some of them, at the expense of the memory required to store the extra link.  On the few occasions I've had to write a binary tree myself I've never used a parent link.

Answer (score 1):

Absent something specifically saying otherwise, a binary tree doesn't normally contain pointers to parents as shown in that diagram. The "pointer to parent" is normally stored implicitly on the stack as you traverse the tree recursively.

There is a rather more common variant -- the "threaded binary tree" -- in this case, the leaf nodes where a normal binary tree would have NULL pointers instead have pointers to the next node in order and the previous node in order. This lets you walk through the tree in forward or reverse order without recursion.

Comment: @luserdroog: you may need to, but it depends on how you intend to use the tree.

Answer (score 0):

The model without the parent node is better suited for recursive divide-and-conquer-style algorithms [for example, an pre-order or post-order traversal].  For more advanced operations, the parent pointer is needed.

What are you trying to do?